# remove author and date from all posts

Tags: css, author, date

I've tried including some code in style.css of my theme, but it didn't work.

Ex:

```
body.blog .posted-on,
body.blog .post-author,
body.blog .post-comments,
body.blog .entry-taxonomy {
  display: none;
}
```

I'm trying to remove the author and the date from the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same issue, I solved it by doing the following:

Within Apparence -> Customize -> Blog Post Options ->

- uncheck "post Date"
- uncheck "post Author"

These settings, removed the author and date from the post.

Then, commenting the following line from single.php

```
/*$cmsms_post_author_box = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cmsms_post_author_box', true);*/
```

And then, I've changed with the following:

```
$cmsms_post_author_box = "";
```

These, removed the bottom "About the author"